# Timer speeds up when moving mouse over Chrome webpage elements

Tags: java, swing, google-chrome, animation

I have created a time lapse to show the density on a highway over the course of a day. The data is held in a `double[][]` array `data`, where `data.length` is 2880 (each index represents a 30-second interval) and `data[0].length` is about 450 (representing a cubic interpolation across the highway section's length).

My code for the time lapse is as follows:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JProgressBar;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class TimeLapse extends JPanel {
    static double[][] data;
    int index = 0;
    double max;
    double lineWidth;
    Timer timer;
    final JProgressBar progressBar = new JProgressBar(0, 2879);
    BufferedImage[] images;
    Color colors[][];

    public static void main(String[] args) {
      data=getData(); //arbitrary method to get interpolated data
      new TimeLapse(data, 90);
    }

    public TimeLapse(double[][] data1, double max) {
      data = data1;
      this.max = max;
      JFrame frame = new JFrame("Timelapse");
      frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 600));
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
      GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
      c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
      c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTH;
      c.gridwidth = 1;
      c.gridx = 0;
      c.gridheight = 1;
      c.weightx = 1;
      c.weighty = .01;
      c.gridy = 0;
      frame.add(progressBar, c);
      c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.SOUTH;
      c.gridy = 1;
      c.gridheight = 9;
      c.weighty = 1;
      frame.add(this, c);
      frame.pack();
      getColorArray();
      frame.setVisible(true);
      int dataLength;
      dataLength = data.length;
      // Make the animation 5 seconds long
      int delay = (int) (5000d / dataLength);
      timer = new Timer(delay, new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
          updateIndex();
          repaint();
          Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync();
        }
      });
      timer.start();
    }

    private void getColorArray() {
      double cutOff = max / 2;
      colors = new Color[data.length][data[0].length];
      for (int index = 0; index < data.length; index++) {
        for (double x = 0; x < data[0].length; x++) {
          colors[index][(int) x] =
            getColor(data[index][(int) x], cutOff);
        }
      }
    }

    private void updateIndex() {
      index = index < data.length - 1 ? index + 1 : 0;
      progressBar.setValue(2879 * index / data.length);
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      super.paintComponent(g);
      Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
      int panelHeight = getHeight();
      lineWidth = ((double) getWidth()) / ((double) (data[0].length));
      // guaranteed counter, as doing it in timer's ActionListener could overlap with rendering

      for (double x = 0; x < data[0].length; x++) {
        g2.setColor(colors[index][(int) x]);
        double rectHeight = panelHeight * data[index][(int) x] / max;
        g2.fillRect((int) (x * lineWidth),
            (int) (panelHeight - rectHeight),
            (int) (lineWidth + 1), (int) rectHeight + 1);
      }
      g2.dispose();
    }

    private Color getColor(double value, double cutOff) {
      int hueR, hueG, hueB = 0;
      if (value < cutOff) {
        hueG = 255;
        hueR = (int) (255 * value / (cutOff));
      } else if (max != cutOff) {
        hueR = 255;
        hueG = (int) (255 - (255 * (value - cutOff) / (max - cutOff)));
      } else {
        hueR = 255;
        hueG = 0;
      }

      hueR = (hueR < 0) ? 0 : ((hueR > 255) ? 255 : hueR);
      hueG = (hueG < 0) ? 0 : ((hueG > 255) ? 255 : hueG);
      hueB = (hueB < 0) ? 0 : ((hueB > 255) ? 255 : hueB);
      return new Color(hueR, hueG, hueB);
    }
}
```

The animation functions smoothly, but it typically takes a great deal longer than the five seconds I set it to, which I chalk up to the constant coloring and generation of hundreds of lines in the panel.

To verify that I was correct and it was indeed much slower than it should be, I used the Google Chrome widget that appears when you Google "stopwatch" to time it. Doing this I found that when I ran the stopwatch the animation sped up greatly, as well as whenever I moved my mouse over certain elements (hyperlinks, the tabs at the top, and seemingly anything else that gives a visual response to the mouse hovering). This only happens when I move the mouse or am running the stopwatch; keeping the mouse still does not speed it up, and it appears to only have this behavior while hovering over Chrome (i.e. any other application is fine). Can anyone explain this odd behavior?

EDIT: It also happens while reloading a tab, but not after it's done reloading.

EDIT 2: I now know for certain that the timer is speeding up. I created a small class with a timer that prints every millisecond an increasing index:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.Timer;

public class TimerTest {
    static int index = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
      Timer t = new Timer(1, new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println(index++);
        }
      });
      t.start();

      while (true) {
      }
    }
}
```

This has exactly the same behavior as the time lapse class, speeding up greatly when moving the mouse over Chrome's elements. I believe the reason is that, in this case, `println` is a slow method and executes slower than the timer updates. Again, can someone explain why Chrome specifically speeds up a backed-up timer?

Answer (score 1):

A painting method is for painting only.

You should not be changing properties of your class in the painting method.

That is you can not control when Swing determines a component needs to be repainted. So there may be some system call that is causing the component to be repainted and therefore changing your properties more frequently than you think.

For example you should not be updating your "index" variable or the progress bar value. Instead your Timer should invoke a method to changes these properties and then that method should invoke repaint on the panel.

> This only happens when I move the mouse

Maybe you have tooltips on the panel which would cause it to be repainted.

This is easy to test, just add a System.out.println(...) statement to the paintComponent() method to see if it displays more frequently than the 5 seconds of your Timer.

Comment: I am aware that you can't predict when `paint` will be called, and I do try to avoid the kind of thing I'm doing here (updating properties in paint method); that is actually what I originally had in this class, but due to the slow rendering speed, `timer` would update the index well before it was ready, leading to some rendering and indexing bugs and errors.

Comment: As far as tooltips go, I am not using any.

Comment: At any rate, I did as you suggested and created a method to update the index and progress bar and put that in the timer (I realized that the former bugs I got don't appear with the new index calculation I'm using). I'll update the code, as the behavior persists.

Comment: `moved my mouse over certain elements` - this might cause a repaint().` Is the paintComponent() method being invoked more frequently than 5 seconds? Is the index incrementing by more than 1 each time the Timer fires? I'm assuming you animation is controlled by the value of the Index, so if this change as expected every 5 seconds then the animation should remain constant. Another option is to paint to a BufferedImage when the Timer fires and have the paintComponent() just paint the BufferedImage. This way you know the image only changes every 5 seconds.

Comment: Added `println(index)` at end of `actionPerformed()` and `println("paintComponent")` at end of `paintComponent()`. `index` counts up by one regardless of speed of animation, and `paintComponent` is called exactly every time `index` updates.

Comment: I want to clarify, also, that the entire animation should be 5 seconds long, not each change.

Comment: Your Timer delay is about 2ms which is too small (and the system can't respond that fast) so I'm guessing the Timer is coalescing events (read the Timer API). I would suggestion you try with maybe a delay of 20ms and increment the index by 10.

Comment: Using 100 seems to fix it, 10 still has the problem.

Comment: I read the API and see where it says that excessively long tasks can bunch up and execute as a whole, but why would Chrome, and only Chrome, have this speeding-up effect?

Comment: Don't know, I've never used Chrome. Maybe Chrome is slower and therefore is causing tasks to take longer and therefore bunch up more.

Comment: This application isn't embedded in Chrome, there's no relation except that they are both on the same computer (different monitors however).